# Gson and arrays

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm building a client server web application and stuck on this:

I'm getting an array of users "FriendsIDList:":

```
"data":{
    "name":"anna",
    "BirthDate":"2010-01-01",
    "FriendsIDList":{
        "email":"anna1@gmail.com",
        "email":"anna2@gmail.com"
    }
}}
```

Without the array I have no problem reading the data like this:

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
gb.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
gson = gb.create();
newUser= gson.fromJson(data, user.class);
```

How can I read this array?  I'm using `LinkedList` in my user class:

```
LinkedList FriendsIDList;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a single user that contains the FriendList then your last line will work as you have mentioned.

Try defining you FriendList property as follows:

```
LinkedList<Email> FriendList;
```

And create Email Class:

```
public class Email {
  private String email;
}
```

Comment: and when should I use this? Do I still need to use my last line?

Comment: It means that you have to provide the type of data that is returned from json. If json is returning a list you have to create a Type for list and pass that in the fromJson method

Comment: According to your last line you are expecting a single user object (user.class). But now you have changed your json structure and returning a list or users. So you need to replace the last line with my code

Comment: @Nusha lets join the chat room to discuss this in detail

Comment: I believe that the answer that you are seeking is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223023/parsing-json-with-gson-object-sometimes-contains-list-sometimes-contains-object

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627) says this:

> A name is a string. A single colon comes after each name, separating
>   the name from the value. A single comma separates a value from a
>   following name. **The names within an object SHOULD be unique.**

Unfortunately Gson doesn't natively support non-unique names in name/value pairs. So it cannot properly handle your 'email' properties:

```
{"email":"anna1@gmail.com","email":"anna2@gmail.com"}
```

You can work-around this by writing your own [TypeAdapter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html). Your implementation should accumulate email strings into a list. You'll probably want to use a special wrapper object in your data model like EmailAddressList to make this easy.

```
static class FriendsIDList {
  List<String> emails;
}

static TypeAdapter<FriendsIDList> friendsIDListAdapter
        = new TypeAdapter<FriendsIDList>() {
    ... // code to read and write emails
}
```