# How to deserialize object or array

Tags: java, gson

How to handle name from children. I'm using `gson`.
here is my code and i get illegalstateexception : expected Begin object but was begin array at line ..
i don't know how to iterate gson object

```
        Reader reader = jSONParser.getGSONFromUrl(url);
    Root response=null;
    try {
        response = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Root.class);
        person
        = new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(response.person.clone()));
       children 
       = new ArrayList<Child>(Arrays.asList(response.Children.clone()));
       job
        = response.job;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("JSONReader "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public class Root{  
    @SerializedName("person")       
    Person[] persons;
    @SerializedName("job")
    Job job;
    @SerializedName("children")
    Child[] children;
```

}

```
    class Child{ 
    int cID;
    List<String>names;
}


{
person:[{}, {}, {}..], 

job:{..},

children:{"cID":"1", "name":{"firstname":"mark"}} 

}
```

or

```
{

person:[{}, {}, {}..],

job:{..},

children:{"cID":"1", "name":[{"firstname":"mark"}, {"firstname":"jan"}, {"firstname":"tamara"}...]}

}
```

How to handle name from children. I'm using `gson`.
here is my code and i get illegalstateexception : expected Begin object but was begin array at line ..
i don't know how to iterate gson object

Comment: class Root{ List<Person> persons; Job job; Child}

Comment: The above comment is not valid Java.  Please post the class you are trying to deserialize into, as well as the error (if any) or other symptoms that you are seeing, and what you expect to see.

Comment: As I understand the problem description, custom deserialization is necessary to handle the situation where the JSON is sometimes an array and sometimes an object. Using Gson to handle this specific issue has been covered in previous StackOverflow threads, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223023/parsing-json-with-gson-object-sometimes-contains-list-sometimes-contains-object/6225906#6225906 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array. This information is based on an older version of Gson. It's possible that a newer release added or will add a configurati

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with GSON, object sometimes contains list sometimes contains object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223023/parsing-json-with-gson-object-sometimes-contains-list-sometimes-contains-object)

Answer (score 0):

To get to the name you need to have the following path:

`children.name`

If you have an array of firstnames, you should access as an array:

`children.name.firstname[number]`

Since your "name" is an Object type, you can refer to any of it's fields via "."

Comment: I think the OP is trying to deserialize this JSON into Java and having some sort of trouble doing so.  It's still unclear what the error is, though.

Comment: Well, he did ask about the document and the document is present as code. If he attaches more details, it would be more clear, I agree.

Comment: Sure, good point!  We'll just have to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: i'm getting JSONReader java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 5161216

Comment: So why don't you provide the correct code, full stacktrace of exception and form your question more clear? Also, I'm a bit confused of "column 516216" in line 1(!) ... Can you imagine that document?

Comment: Well, just copy and past it to here via "edit" button. Look it right below the post you created. I will edit it if it is not going to look in proper way.

Comment: i get "Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above." more details..

Comment: Please, indicate what error do you get, It has to be shown above while editing.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov - His problem is that `name` inside the `Child` object can either be an object or an array, and that's why this is a dup. He has to handle this exactly as the answer to the question this is a dup of states. And that's ignoring that his `Root` class currently has `Child[]` which is completely incorrect; that's never an array.

Comment: thanks i found the answer under the link from "programmer Bruce" thanks a lot